# Wordpress exploited theme is causing high io load on server

Tags: security

I used a Wordpress theme for a while that was causing high IO-load on my server. That was because there was some kind of exploits made/available for the theme: http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/29150/ . So I deleted my theme, installed another, but "they" are keep coming back. Because the domain name is somewhere registered that it is vulnerable or something like that. What can I do to stop this? Moving it to another server isn't the solution I guess, because they're pointing to the domain name. I've already blocked IP-ranges from outside my country, they're pointing to a "forbidden" html page then, but still it are a lot of "things", so the io load stays high.

Comment: Did you get the theme from that website?

Comment: No. Bought it a while back, before that exploit was made public, at Themeforest. The theme is now removed, and I'm using another. But they're still trying to reach the files from the exploit. And that is causing a lot of IO-server-load.

Comment: Have you spoken to the guys at themeforest? My thinking here is that they should have had this issue with a lots a people how used that specific theme, and they might have a solution to that problem

Comment: So your installation is clean, it is just that people try to access this file that isn't even there any more?

Comment: That is correct @kraftner

Comment: Have you tried blocking access to the file on `.htaccess` level? This will cause the least server load.

Comment: I only accept IPs from my country online. I redirect the others to a 403 Forbidden page. Still a lot of server load.

Comment: Define "coming back"? It is hard to discern what is actual cause of your IO issue symptoms or if you have a fix on that cause at all.